# I have a 10,000,000 Turkish bill but it's only half the bill, is it worth anything?

Tags: banking, currency, turkey

I have a 10,000,000 Turkish bill but it's only half the bill, is it worth anything ?

Answer (score 6):

The 10,000,000 equivalent to new 10 Turkish Lira were discontinued in 2004. About 2.5 USD in face value.

However as this is quite old and half torn; there isn't any value.

Comment: To clarify, this bill has no value because it is no longer legal tender and it is too common and too damaged to have any collector's value, correct?

Comment: @DanielCarson Spot on.